# Detecting instance of data change

Tags: influxdb

Is there a good way to write a query in influxdb that will show you a change of state from the previous value? I am looking to query my database for times of where a server has turned off.

For example if I had the following database:

```
Time                 | Server_1_ON | Server_2_ON
-------------------------------------------------
2019-08-18T14:43:00Z | True        | True
2019-08-18T14:43:05Z | True        | True
2019-08-18T14:43:10Z | True        | False
2019-08-18T14:43:15Z | True        | False
2019-08-18T14:43:20Z | True        | False
2019-08-18T14:43:25Z | True        | True
2019-08-18T14:43:30Z | True        | True
2019-08-18T14:43:35Z | True        | False
```

I would want to be able to detect that server 2 had turned off twice, and return the two rows

```
2019-08-18T14:43:10Z | True        | False
2019-08-18T14:43:35Z | True        | False
```

I could achieve the same results by writing a query to

```
SELECT * WHERE "Server_2_ON" = False
```

and then filtering out duplicate results. But this is a multi-step process.

If this is not easily possible in influxdb, is there another database that is more suited to this style of query?

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#distinct   is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It will help - but not allow me to do this in a single step. This will only show me values that are the same within a grouping - I could possibly query for the groupings and then based on those groupings detect a change- which is still a two part query - but it would at least group similar values together.

Answer (score 1):

If your measurements were integer (1 to represent ON / 0 for OFF) instead of boolean, you could use the [difference](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#difference) function.

To select any change in either measurement:

```
WHERE (DIFFERENCE(Server_1_ON) != 0
    OR DIFFERENCE(Server_2_ON) != 0)
```

to select change from on to off in either measurement:

```
WHERE (DIFFERENCE(Server_1_ON) = -1
    OR DIFFERENCE(Server_2_ON) = -1)
```

Note that in InfluxDb v1.x it is not possible to cast from Boolean to Integer, so for this to work you will need to change the stored data type to int. See [can I change a field’s data type?](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-change-a-field-s-data-type)

> "There is no way to cast a float or integer to a string or Boolean (or
>   vice versa). The simplest workaround is to begin writing the new data type to a  different field in the same series.

In InfluxDb v2.0 (still alpha) it *is* possible to cast Boolean to Int (see [INT](https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/built-in/transformations/type-conversions/int/)  function).

(I have just started to investigate InfluxDb. I don't like it so far. But it seems that's just me, for according to [this article in DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/4-best-time-series-databases-to-watch-in-2019) it's currently the no 1 Time Series Database.)

Comment: Unfortunately DIFFERENCE is not a valid function call in a WHERE statement. 
SELECT * FROM "data_set" WHERE DIFFERENCE(Server_1_ON) != 0 
gives me the error:
ERR: invalid function call in condition: difference(Server_1_ON)

Comment: @BenW Sorry to hear that didn't work - I found your question when I was trying sometime similar.